# Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$thumbnailLink

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, pagination

I am trying to get data from my table and show it in my view and paginate this data. I received this problem and couldn't find any solution. I did the exactly same thing in my previous project and it worked well.

here is my controller

```
foreach ($userDetails->wanttoread as $key => $bookid) {
    $bookDetails = DB::table('books')->where('_id', $bookid)->paginate(10);
    array_push($wanttoreadArr, $bookDetails);
  }
$data['wanttoread'] = $wanttoreadArr;
return view('frontend.user.userShelve')->with($data);
```

And this is my view

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($wanttoread as $book)
    <tr>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book->thumbnailLink) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: replace this `array_push($wanttoreadArr, $bookDetails);` with `array_push($wanttoreadArr, $bookDetails->data);`

Comment: @rkj I'm getting Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$data

Comment: {"current_page":1,"data":[{"_id":{"$oid":"5b265874df86fc3d5800278c"},"book_.... This is how I'm getting if I dump the values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve this in two ways

1 solution-change blade

```
<tbody>
    @foreach($wanttoread as $books)
        @foreach($books as $book)
            <tr>
                <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book["thumbnailLink"]) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></td>
           </tr>
        @endforeach
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```

2 solution chage controller logic(best solution getting paginated result and all time same count items)

```
$bookDetails = DB::table('books')->whereIn('_id', $userDetails->wanttoread)->paginate(10);
$data['wanttoread'] = $wanttoreadArr;
return view('frontend.user.userShelve')->with($data);
```

Comment: 1st solution throw me this Trying to get property 'thumbnailLink' of non-object

Comment: 2nd solution gave me this Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: for second solution are you change blade??You must not change blade only controller

Comment: <tbody>
  @foreach($wanttoread as $book)
    <tr>
      <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book->thumbnailLink) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></td>
    </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>

Comment: Undefined property: Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator::$thumbnailLink

Comment: I think you  change blade and controller togather. Can you show now your controller and blade??

Comment: $bookDetails = DB::table('books')->whereIn('_id', $userDetails->wanttoread)->paginate(10);
      $data['wanttoread'] = $bookDetails;

Comment: <tbody>
            @foreach($wanttoread as $book)
            <tr>
              <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book->thumbnailLink) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
          </tbody>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173389/discussion-between-davit-and-raghu-acharya).

Answer (score 1):

you can try this (Leave your controller code as it is)

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($wanttoread as $row)
     @foreach($row->items() as $book)
       <tr>
         <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book['thumbnailLink']) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive"></td>
       </tr>
    @endforeach
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: Trying to get property 'thumbnailLink' of non-object

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are getting a LengthAwarePaginator, you need to get the items that are currently being paginated, so you could do the following:

```
<tbody>
@foreach($wanttoread->items() as $book)
<tr>
  <td><img src="{{ URL::to($book->thumbnailLink) }}" class="img-thumbnail img-responsive">
</td>
</tr>
@endforeach
```

The items() function will return the dataset. You can find out more at the official API [docs](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html).

Comment: Call to a member function item() on array